# Drupal 7 - div popup inside the overlay (node/123/edit)

Tags: 7, modal-dialogs

I'm trying to display a pop up dialog (using a hidden block) inside the overlay when editing a node.

When i click to edit a node, the overlay appears with all the custom fields of a given content type as usual. It is clean and white and everything in the background is darkened out.

So now i have logic in place (using jQUery) that's supposed to change my div's display to 'show' on keyup for a specific field on top of the overlay edit node.

I've tried adding a z-index of over 1000 and still nothing. The drupal overlay is using a z-index of 501 but my custom div still wont display on top of/over it.

**This is my CSS for the hidden block:**

```
#block-block-block-26 {
  z-index: 2000 !important;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

**This is my function inside jQuery:**

```
 $('#edit-field-pi-estimated-ini-capital-und-0-value').keyup(function() {
        var txtVal = this.value;
        if(txtVal == 0 && txtVal != '') {
          $('#block-block-block-26').show();
          return false;
        }
  });
```

any idea how to make my div appear over the overlay?

Thanks

Comment: unless you have modified it appropriately, due to conflict avoidance, the jQuery in Drupal doesn't allow the $ shortcut.  Use 'jQuery' instead. Are you sure your css is targeting the correct block?

Comment: Yea I made sure that the right block is targeted. This is fairly simple to reproduce. Create a new block, slap it on the side region, give it a z-index of 1000, and open a edit page. That'll bring up the overlay. In theory the block should appear on top over the overlay because the block z-index is much higher. Yet it doesn't. It's as if the overlay is a completely different page where the page view elements aren't accessible no longer once it appears.

Comment: it works for me. but the block name is different - mine shows a block id="block-block-4" not an equivalent to your "block-block-block-4"

Comment: That is odd. I'm using a custom theme btw. I'll have to test this using the default theme and see if it'll work. The theme is probably where the bottleneck is. Well, thank you for taking a poke at this and confirming that it does actually work.

Comment: I was using a custom theme as well... does it show if you remove the display:none? I ask in case it is a JS problem, not a css problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is fine, problem was with jquery version.

Comment: Never use form field ID's, as they're not static. Use a preprocess or a form_alter to add a class, then target using that class.